# Restoring a live database to another database name

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Hey so I currently have 3 databases one is a Production, one is a Test, and one is a Dev.  I currently need to bring all data and columns with proper constraints from Production to my new Test and Dev databases.  The problem I'm running into is that I can't insert the values of the ID column into their rows because it's an autoincrement identity column.  <strike>Is there a way for me to insert the correct ids and data to the correct rows and then add on the constraints after the table has been populated?</strike>

**EDIT 1:**

[image: Failure inserting into the read-only column "id"]

I'm using the Import & Export Wizard where I'm trying to copy this data over to an appropriately constrained DB.

Comment: Use `IDENTITY_INSERT`.

Comment: You would not need to "insert" anything if you were using an actual [restore command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). This sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Are you *restoring* or *copying* - very different operations.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable IDENTITY_INSERT in Import Export Wizard.
[image]